# Python paradigm for "derived fields"/"class attributes from calculations"

Tags: python, oop, attributes, properties, class-attributes

I have a class that, let's say, computes a person's insurance risk, and a few other variables are computed during computation. I will need access to the risk and the other variables later.

```
class InsuranceRiskModel:

    self.risk = None
    self.other_var = None
    ...

    def get_risk():
        # do a bunch of calculations, 
        # which in the meantime fills out a bunch of other vars
        self.other_var = 5
        self.risk = 6
        return self.risk

    def get_other_var():
        # risk hasn't been calculated
        if not self.risk:
            raise NotYetCalculatedError("Not yet calculated!")
        return self.other_var
```

Now in some other function I do:

```
r = InsuranceRiskModel(person)
risk = r.get_risk()
other_var = r.get_other_var()
```

Is this a legitimate structure for the sort of program I want? Just throw an exception of the computation hasn't been run, to prevent getting bogus values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a legitimate thing to raise a `NotYetCalculatedError` ever, in any program (unless the calculation would take hours of work).

`get_other_var()` should automatically calculate the risk

What you actually want to do is **run all the calculations when you initialize the class**, or if you can't do that, you'll want to do this:

```
class InsuranceRiskModel(object):
    def __init__(self, person):
        self.person = person
        self.calculated = False

    def calculateModel(self):
        if not self.calculated:
            self.risk = 6
            self.other_var = 5
            self.calculated = True

    @property
    def risk(self):
        self.calculateModel()
        return self.risk

    @property
    def other_var(self):
        self.calculateModel()
        return self.other_var
```

Then you can access `InsuranceRiskModel(bob).risk` or `InsuranceRiskModel(bob).other_var` anytime and the calculations will be done transparently.

To answer your more general question, the "python paradigm for [class attributes represented by] stored calculations" is the class property abstraction, involving transparent user-defined getters and setters and deleters, as demonstrated above; more info here http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Comment: Word, this makes much more sense. Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
def get_other_var():
    # risk hasn't been calculated
    if not self.risk:
        self.risk = self.get_risk()
    return self.other_var
```

?

It is not Python specific.  If users of you class need `other_var` and it is mandatory that `risk` should be calculated before it, it is better just calculate it silently.